# Infer elastic search type from index name in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to infer type of elastic search document by index name, since I'm trying to call multiple indices and have to use `object` type.

```
        var indices = Indices.Index(entities);

        var search = new SearchRequest(indices)
        {
            From = page,
            Size = pageSize,
            Query = fullQuery,
            IgnoreUnavailable = true,
        };

        var response = this.client.Search<object>(search);
```

Is it possible to have each object infer type from elastic search, based on some type/indexName mapping?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try out Generics.

```
var indices = Indices.Index(entities);

var search = new SearchRequest(indices)
{
    From = page,
    Size = pageSize,
    Query = fullQuery,
    IgnoreUnavailable = true,
};

var response = this.client.Search<T>(search);
return response;
```